# Write File name as column header

Tags: r

I have a loop that looks at a group of files, takes the 4th column and combines them together. I would like like to append the filename that comes after the "Output" folder as the header of the column.

```
files2 <- list.files(path="c:/Users/~/Output",pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)

newdata <- (1:51)

for(ii in files2){

titlename2<- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(files2)) 
#genes <- read.csv(files2[1], header=True)[,1]     # gene names
mydata2 <-read.csv(ii, header = T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
mydata2<- mydata2[,4]


newdata <- cbind(newdata,mydata2)
colnames(newdata)= c(files2)

}
```

However, when I try and apply the filename I get the following error:

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  ``length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

How do I apply the file name as the column header?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try assigning the new name to the single column data.frame, `mydata2`, prior to binding.  Right now you are trying to assign a single name to your "growing" dataset `newdata`, which leads to the error since you don't have enough names for all the columns.

Comment: I tried `colnames(mydata2)= titlename2` but got the error `Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = ii) : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions`

Comment: Oh, I see, you are pulling out a vector (I was thinking you were pulling out a data.frame).  If you pull out a data.frame (`mydata2[, 4, drop = FALSE]`) instead of a vector you can then assign the name to the column.

Comment: could you please add the solution? i have the similar problem but it is not working your code above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that `colnames(newdata)` and `c(files2)` do not have the same length.

You could for example move `colnames(newdata) = c(files2)` after the for loop and replace `c(files2)` by something like `c("ID", files2)` (as you have `length(files2) + 1` columns).

Comment: For some reason I had to do this in two lines, but it worked.

`sumhead = c("WS",titlename2)
colnames(newdata) = sumhead`